# Nagios python script wait for execution

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, subprocess

I have this script which is run by nagios which checks the provider API if mitigation is enabled and reports back. I just copied an example from Nagios, I have no Python knowledge whatsoever. The problem is that sometimes the scripts needs 10 seconds to run and python just continues, so I need it to wait for execution.

I found some examples using subprocess which were successful but I don't know how to add the .readline and .strip to the command.

This is the original script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os, sys
mitigation_enabled=os.popen("/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_mitigation.py 
| grep auto | awk '{print $2}'").readline().strip()

if mitigation_enabled == "false":
    print "OK - Mitigation disabled." .format (mitigation_enabled)
    sys.exit(0)
elif mitigation_enabled == "true":
    print "WARNING - Mitigation enabled." .format (mitigation_enabled)
    sys.exit(1)
else:
    print "UKNOWN - mitigation status unknown." .format (mitigation_enabled)
    sys.exit(2)
```

So how do I make this with subprocess, wait for the execution of the external script and add the .readline and .strip values?

Short question, how to make this work :)

Thanks!

Comment: Why is the question tagged with both Python versions?

Answer (score 0):

You are complaining that the ancient historic API permits "short reads" of zero bytes.
Yes, that is correct, it is working as designed.

Recommend you use [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output) directly.

Also, two nits about `awk '{print $2}'`:

1. Delete the `grep` by invoking `awk '/auto/ {print $2}'`.
2. Delete the overhead of the `awk` child by using [split()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split).